# Fields are not editable using React Hook Form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-redux

I have this `UserEditScreen.js` file where in I am pulling up all the data from mongodb via React-Redux.

I need to incorporate some validation so I used [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) to do this. So on my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import  Message from '../components/Message'
import  Loader from '../components/Loader'
import { getUserDetails, updateUser } from '../actions/userActions'
import { USER_UPDATE_RESET } from '../constants/userConstants'

const UserEditScreen = ({ match, history }) => {

    const { watch, register, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm()
    console.log('role')

    const userId = match.params.id

    // const [name, setName] = useState('')
    // const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    // const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')
    // const [role, setRole] = useState('')

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const userDetails = useSelector(state => state.userDetails)
    const { loading, error, user } = userDetails 

    const userUpdate = useSelector(state => state.userUpdate)
    const { loading:loadingUpdate, error:errorUpdate, success:successUpdate } = userUpdate 

     useEffect(() => {

       if(successUpdate){
           dispatch({ type: USER_UPDATE_RESET })
           history.push('/admin/userslist')
       } else {
        if(!user.name || user._id !== userId){
            dispatch(getUserDetails(userId))
        }
        // else {
        //      setName(user.name)
        //      setEmail(user.email)
        //      setPhone(user.phone)
        //      setRole(user.role)
        //  }
       }
     }, [dispatch, history, userId, user, successUpdate])

    const submitHandler = (data, e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const {name, email, phone, role } = data
        dispatch(updateUser({ _id: userId, name, email, phone, role  }))
    }

    return ( 
        <>
            <h1>Edit User</h1>
            { loadingUpdate && <Loader /> }
    { errorUpdate && <Message variant='danger'>{errorUpdate}</Message>}
    { loading ? <Loader /> : error ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message> : (
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler}> 
            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="name"
                            value={user.name}
                            className={`form-control ${errors.name ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                            id="name"
                            ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 2, maxLength: 30 })}
                        />
                        { errors.name && errors.name.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Name is required.</p> }
                        { errors.name && errors.name.type ==='minLength' && <p className="text-danger">Name is too short.</p> }
                        { errors.name && errors.name.type ==='maxLength' && <p className="text-danger">Name is exceeds maximum length.</p> }
                    </div>
                    
            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                        <input
                            type="email"
                            name="email"
                            value={user.email}
                            className={`form-control ${errors.email ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                            id="email"
                            ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 8, maxLength: 30, pattern: /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/ })}
                        />
                        { errors.email && errors.email.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Email is required.</p> }
                        { errors.email && errors.email.type ==='minLength' && <p className="text-danger">Email length is too small.</p> }
                        { errors.email && errors.email.type ==='maxLength' && <p className="text-danger">Email exceeds maximum length.</p> }
                        { errors.email && errors.email.type ==='pattern' && <p className="text-danger">That is not a valid email.</p> }
            </div>
            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={user.phone}
                            className={`form-control ${errors.phone ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                            id="phone"
                            ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 10, maxLength: 13, pattern: /^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$/})}
                        />
                        { errors.phone && errors.phone.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Phone is required.</p> }
                        { errors.phone && errors.phone.type ==='minLength' && <p className="text-danger">Phone length is too small.</p> }
                        { errors.phone && errors.phone.type ==='maxLength' && <p className="text-danger">Phone exceeds maximum length.</p> }
                        { errors.phone && errors.phone.type ==='pattern' && <p className="text-danger">Phone is not a valid phone.</p> }
            </div>
            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="phone">User Role</label>
                        <div class="role">
                        <input 
                   type="radio" 
                   className="btn-check" 
                   name="role" 
                   id="administrator" 
                   autocomplete="off"  
                   value='administrator'
                   ref={register({ required: true })}
                   checked={user.role === 'administrator'}
                    />
                <label className="btn btn-outline-success" for="administrator">Administrator</label>
                <input 
                   type="radio" 
                   className="btn-check" 
                   name="role" 
                   id="resort-owner" 
                   autocomplete="off"  
                   value='resortOwner'
                    ref={register({ required: true })}
                    checked={user.role === 'resortOwner'}
                    />
                <label className="btn btn-outline-success" for="resort-owner">Resort Owner</label>
                <input 
                   type="radio" 
                   className="btn-check"
                   name="role" 
                   id="reviewer" 
                   autocomplete="off" 
                   value='reviewer'
                    ref={register({ required: true })}
                    checked={user.role === 'reviewer'}
                />
                <label className="btn btn-outline-success" for="reviewer">Reviewer</label>
                { errors.role && errors.role.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Choose a role.</p> }
             </div>

            </div>
        
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            </form>
            
    )}

        </>
    )
}

export default UserEditScreen
```

As you can see I commented out the `useState` fields and tried to pulled the data from `userDetails` action directly via `user.name`, `user.email` etc.. which I setup via each input fields value attribute.

However, doing this, I was not able to modify or edit any fields anymore. I need to set some validation but hoping still to be able to edit each fields and submit the form using react hook form but I am not sure how to fix this.

Any idea how can I fix this and make the form fields editable as well as be able to submit the form with the validations using react hook form? Please help.

**UPDATE**: I tried using `defaultValue` instead of `value` so it works on name, email, phone but now I can't select or modify the value of `role` the radio button one. Here's my updated code.

```
const UserEditScreen = ({ match, history }) => {

const { watch, register, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm()
console.log(watch('name'))
console.log(watch('email'))
console.log(watch('phone'))
console.log(watch('role'))

const userId = match.params.id

// const [name, setName] = useState('')
// const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
// const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')
// const [role, setRole] = useState('')

const dispatch = useDispatch()

const userDetails = useSelector(state => state.userDetails)
const { loading, error, user } = userDetails 

const userUpdate = useSelector(state => state.userUpdate)
const { loading:loadingUpdate, error:errorUpdate, success:successUpdate } = userUpdate 

 useEffect(() => {

   if(successUpdate){
       dispatch({ type: USER_UPDATE_RESET })
       history.push('/admin/userslist')
   } else {
    if(!user.name || user._id !== userId){
        dispatch(getUserDetails(userId))
    }

    // else {
    //      setName(user.name)
    //      setEmail(user.email)
    //      setPhone(user.phone)
    //      setRole(user.role)
    //  }
   }
 }, [dispatch, history, userId, user, successUpdate,])

const submitHandler = (data, e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const {name, email, phone, role } = data
    dispatch(updateUser({ _id: userId, name, email, phone, role  }))
}

return ( 
    <>
        <h1>Edit User</h1>
        { loadingUpdate && <Loader /> }
{ errorUpdate && <Message variant='danger'>{errorUpdate}</Message>}
{ loading ? <Loader /> : error ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message> : (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitHandler)}> 
        <div className="form-group"> 
            <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        defaultValue={user.name}
                        className={`form-control ${errors.name ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                        id="name"
                        ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 2, maxLength: 30 })}
                    />
                    { errors.name && errors.name.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Name is required.</p> }
                    { errors.name && errors.name.type ==='minLength' && <p className="text-danger">Name is too short.</p> }
                    { errors.name && errors.name.type ==='maxLength' && <p className="text-danger">Name is exceeds maximum length.</p> }
                </div>
                
        <div className="form-group"> 
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        defaultValue={user.email}
                        className={`form-control ${errors.email ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                        id="email"
                        ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 8, maxLength: 30, pattern: /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/ })}
                    />
                    { errors.email && errors.email.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Email is required.</p> }
                    { errors.email && errors.email.type ==='minLength' && <p className="text-danger">Email length is too small.</p> }
                    { errors.email && errors.email.type ==='maxLength' && <p className="text-danger">Email exceeds maximum length.</p> }
                    { errors.email && errors.email.type ==='pattern' && <p className="text-danger">That is not a valid email.</p> }
        </div>
        <div className="form-group"> 
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="phone"
                        defaultValue={user.phone}
                        className={`form-control ${errors.phone ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                        id="phone"
                        ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 10, maxLength: 13 })}
                    />
                    { errors.phone && errors.phone.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Phone is required.</p> }
                    { errors.phone && errors.phone.type ==='minLength' && <p className="text-danger">Phone length is too small.</p> }
                    { errors.phone && errors.phone.type ==='maxLength' && <p className="text-danger">Phone exceeds maximum length.</p> }
                    { errors.phone && errors.phone.type ==='pattern' && <p className="text-danger">Phone is not a valid phone.</p> }
        </div>
        <div className="form-group"> 
            <label for="phone">User Role</label>
                    <div class="role">
                    <input 
               type="radio" 
               className="btn-check" 
               name="role" 
               id="administrator" 
               autocomplete="off"  
               value='administrator'
               ref={register({ required: true })}
               checked={user.role === 'administrator'}
                />
            <label className="btn btn-outline-success" for="administrator">Administrator</label>
            <input 
               type="radio" 
               className="btn-check" 
               name="role" 
               id="resort-owner" 
               autocomplete="off"  
               value='resortOwner'
                ref={register({ required: true })}
                checked={user.role === 'resortOwner'}
                />
            <label className="btn btn-outline-success" for="resort-owner">Resort Owner</label>
            <input 
               type="radio" 
               className="btn-check"
               name="role" 
               id="reviewer" 
               autocomplete="off" 
               value='reviewer'
                ref={register({ required: true })}
                checked={user.role === 'reviewer'}
            />
            <label className="btn btn-outline-success" for="reviewer">Reviewer</label>
            { errors.role && errors.role.type ==='required' && <p className="text-danger">Choose a role.</p> }
         </div>

        </div>
    
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </form>
        
)}

    </>
)
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using `defaultValue` instead of `value`?

Comment: I did but it won't watch nor edit the `phone` or the `role` (radio button) any idea?

Comment: I tried using `watch` on both `phone` and `role` to console.log them but I can't change or modify them.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried using defaultValue instead of value so it works on name, email, phone but now I can't select or modify the value of role the radio button one. Updated code above.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `value` attribute on `input`s. React will render form controls uneditable if you don't provide a value for `onChange` as well. Use `reset` method of hook to set field values asynchronously instead:

```js
const { watch, register, errors, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();
...
useEffect(() => {
  reset({
    name: user.name,
    email: user.email,
    ...
  });
}, [reset, user]);
```

Read the [React docs on controlled form components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

See [example on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-from-async-set-form-values-ztpd6)

Comment: Not sure but it's not picking up the phone and the role. I updated my question above. Also I am picking up some data on the database via redux FYI not just a regular create form its an edit form

Comment: UPDATE: I tried using defaultValue instead of value so it works on name, email, phone but now I can't select or modify the value of role the radio button one. Updated code above.

Comment: Do not use `value` or `defaultValue` attributes on the `input`s. Have a look at the react form hook code examples, they can show you the correct way to do what you need: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/tree/master/examples

Answer (score -2):

I think so you must try use `onChange` or other listener to inputs and set inner value from listener callback. The inner value is your state. It's normally React use for controlled inputs and setting value on `onChange` re-renders this component with new value and will be editable. Try ;)

Comment: React Hook Form is designed to be used with uncontrolled input fields as the default so this is not a good answer to the OPs question.

Comment: I agree. I tried what he said and did not work at all. Thanks Mark.